# When does $ (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \leq 4+4abc ~ $ hold?

Tags: inequality

When I use $a = 0.1 , b = 1 , c = 10~ $ the following ineqaulity,  $$ (1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \leq 4+4abc ~~~ ....~~~ (*) $$ does not hold.
However, it holds for several other positive numbers $a,b,c$. Therefore, the question is how to find out for what positive values of $a,b,c$ the inequality (*) holds.

Comment: it holds iff $3abc-ab-bc-ca-a-b-c+3\geq 0$.  There are no more simplification available.

Comment: @user10354138 I think it's rather presumptious of you to claim that it's impossible to simplify further. It may be impossible, but it may also just be quite difficult. Or maybe it's rather simple, but you just missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $0\le a,b,c \le 1 $ or $a,b,c \ge 1$, we have
$$(1-a)(1-bc) \ge 0,~~ (1-b)(1-ca) \ge 0,~~ (1-c)(1-ab) \ge 0~~~~(1).$$
Expanding and adding these three results and next by adding $1+abc$ on both sides, we prove that
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) \le  4+4 abc~~~~(2).$$ For other positive numbers, it (2) may or may not hold.